# Using paste in R including a comma

Tags: r, paste

I have a string I wish to paste in R that contains a comma (as below): how do I escape it?

```
variable <-"string"
```

Command 1:

```
lm(paste(variable," ~ ., DATA",sep=""))
```

Error message 1:

```
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:9: unexpected ','
```

Command 2:

```
lm(paste(variable," ~ .\, DATA",sep=""))
```

Error message 2:

```
Error: '\,' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "" ~ .\,"
```

Desired output:

```
lm(string ~ ., DATA)
```

I understand why I am getting the error messages, but I can't work out how to print a literal comma using paste.

EDIT: Agree paste works fine alone, is inside lm(), is this causing problem?

Comment: by setting `variable` as a string `string`, your code works well and does not produce any error to me. Maybe you have to provide what `variable` is, maybe there lies the problem.

Comment: The first one works for me.  I am using `R 3.2.1`

Comment: The first works for me too. Please show a sample of what `variable` is.

Comment: You may need to wrap with `as.formula`.  A reproducible example would be great.  As `string` is the dependent variable, I would expect it to be numeric.

Comment: `DATA` must be another argument of `lm` and should not be included in `paste`. This should work: `lm(paste(variable," ~ .",sep=""),DATA)`.

Comment: This could also be solved by declaring a comma as a value (`comma <- c(",")`) and then using that in a paste0 string (`paste0("hello ",comma,"world")`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't in paste.  It's in `lm`.  The comma is not expected in a formula so when it goes to convert your pasted string (which works correctly, pull it out of the `lm` and you will see this) into a formula it barfs at you.

Additionally, given what you are expecting to happen, this is not the correct way to go about it.  If you want to do metaprogramming in this instance like this you should be constructing the whole command (i.e. `lm(string ~ ., DATA)`) as a string and then using `eval` and `parse`.  All of that said, this is an absolutely terrible programming paradigm to adopt.  Just construct the function call as normally or at least use `do.call`.

Comment: As you might be able to guess from the fact I'm asking this question, I'm far from an expert in R, so could you explain why this is "a terrible programming paradigm", please?

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to second nicola's comment above in the edits section, and iShouldUseAName's warning about the formula. For example, the below works, and I think it's close to what you were doing.

```
X <- 1:5
Y <- 2:6
Z <- 3:7
variable <- "X"
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(X, Y, Z))
lm(paste(variable," ~ Z",sep=""),data)
```

So then if you wanted to loop lm across a few variables (which is how I've tried to use "paste" in the past) you could do something like the below. Apologies if this is not where you were going with this:

```
for (C in c("X","Y")) {
  out <- lm(paste(C," ~ Z",sep=""),data)
  print(out)
}
```